# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.portlet.context.ConfigurablePortletApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, nosuchmethoderror, jboss-portal

I'm trying to deploy my application on jboss-portal-2.7.2, and it is giving me the following error:

```
04:17:23,879 INFO  [DispatcherPortlet] FrameworkPortlet 'my_portlet': initialization started
04:17:23,882 ERROR [LifeCycle] Cannot start object
org.jboss.portal.portlet.container.PortletInitializationException: The portlet my_portlet threw an error during init
    at org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.jsr168.PortletContainerImpl.start(PortletContainerImpl.java:292)
    at org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.PortletContainerLifeCycle.invokeStart(PortletContainerLifeCycle.java:76)
    at org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.LifeCycle.managedStart(LifeCycle.java:92)
    at org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.container.PortletApplicationLifeCycle.startDependents(PortletApplicationLifeCycle.java:351)
...
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:610)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.portlet.context.ConfigurablePortletApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:345)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:116)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.init(GenericPortlet.java:107)
    at org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.jsr168.PortletContainerImpl.initPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:417)
    at org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.jsr168.PortletContainerImpl.start(PortletContainerImpl.java:256)
    ... 76 more
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

MainController:

```
package myportlet.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.RenderMapping;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import javax.portlet.PortletPreferences;
import javax.portlet.PortletRequest;
import javax.portlet.PortletSession;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
@Controller(value = "mainController")
public class MainController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String init(@RequestParam(value = "key", required = false) String key, Model model, PortletRequest request) throws Exception {
        PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession();

        /* Get Key from Portlet Preferences */
        PortletPreferences preferences = request.getPreferences();
        String preferencesKey = preferences.getValue(constants.KEY, constants.FACTORY);
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(key)) {
            key = preferencesKey;
        }

        /* Save current KEY into session */
        session.setAttribute(constants.KEY, key, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);

        model.addAttribute("entityList", getEntities());
        model.addAttribute("preferencesKey", preferencesKey);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

[pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/35Efzzrc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.portlet.context.ConfigurablePortletApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

It sounds like you are using a old version of spring-context.jar [Spring Context API - Version 2.0.x](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html).

Try using a later version [Spring Context API - Version 3.0.x](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html).

Comment: I use spring mvc framework 3.0.4.RELEASE. My pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/35Efzzrc

Comment: Are you using profile local_test? Make sure you are using correct spring version in jboss server(jboss/lib), or simply remove <scope>provided</scope> from your project's pom.xml (under profile local_test).

Comment: I checked the contents of the portlet. There really are two versions of the spring-context - http://3.firepic.org/3/images/2012-07/26/uqb65sn5veam.png I do not understand how he gets into the portlet. I removed <scope>provided</scope> from pom.xml under profile local_test but it has no effect.