# Spring migration from 3.x to 4.2.3 - issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

we almost done with migration of spring project from 3.2.2.Release to 4.2.3.Release successfully, but once we started testing we are facing below issue at multiple places in our application, i guess this some conflict i spent one day i didn't get any solution,

can any one please help to know what might be the issue?

```
 E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause /WEB-INF/views/jsp/planning/individualPlanning.jsp: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/SelectTag.setDisabled&#40;Ljava/lang/String&#59;&#41;V
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:693)
    at com.ibm._jsp._individualPlanning._jspService(_individualPlanning.java:876)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1147)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:722)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:449)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1382)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:191)
```

below are the env details,

```
 java 1.6, webshpere 8.0.0(meets jpa 2.0 servlet specs 3.0 sugggested by spring 4.2.3)
```

below are the jars list used in application,

```
activation-1.1.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-4.2.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
biarengine-12.3.6.1006.jar
biplugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
boconfig-12.3.6.1006.jar
cafinstall-12.3.6.1006.jar
cecore-12.3.6.1006.jar
celib-12.3.6.1006.jar
ceplugins_client-12.3.6.1006.jar
ceplugins_core-12.3.6.1006.jar
ceplugins_cr-12.3.6.1006.jar
cereports-12.3.6.1006.jar
cesdk-12.3.6.1006.jar
cesearch-12.3.6.1006.jar
cesession-12.3.6.1006.jar
cglib-3.1.jar
classworlds-1.1.jar
clientplugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
commons_driver-12.3.6.1006.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-cli-1.0.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-validator-1.4.0.jar
corbaidl-12.3.6.1006.jar
crlov-12.3.6.1006.jar
crlovexternal-12.3.6.1006.jar
crlovmanifest-12.3.6.1006.jar
CrystalCommon2-12.3.6.1006.jar
cvom_chart_lib_en-12.3.6.1006.jar
cvom_chart_lib-12.3.6.1006.jar
cvom-12.3.6.1006.jar
dfc.jar
doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
ebus405-12.3.6.1006.jar
ehcache-core-2.6.10.jar
elf-1.0.jar
i18n4j-12.3.6.1006.jar
itext-1.4.5-12.3.6.1006.jar
jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
jackson-core-2.5.1.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.11.jar
jsch-0.1.27.jar
jsse.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar
jtools-12.3.6.1006.jar
jxl-2.6.jar
jxlib-12.3.6.1006.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
logging-12.3.6.1006.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
mail-1.4.jar
maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar
maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.jar
maven-core-2.0.6.jar
maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.6.jar
maven-filtering-1.0.jar
maven-model-2.0.6.jar
maven-monitor-2.0.6.jar
maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar
maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.6.jar
maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.6.jar
maven-plugin-registry-2.0.6.jar
maven-profile-2.0.6.jar
maven-project-2.0.6.jar
maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
maven-repository-metadata-2.0.6.jar
maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar
maven-settings-2.0.6.jar
mybatis-3.2.3.jar
mybatis-ehcache-1.0.3.jar
mybatis-spring-1.2.1.jar
ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar
plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar
plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar
plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
rasapp-12.3.6.1006.jar
rascore-12.3.6.1006.jar
rebean-12.3.6.1006.jar
rebean.fc-12.3.6.1006.jar
rebean.wi-12.3.6.1006.jar
ReportViewer-12.3.6.1006.jar
serialization-12.3.6.1006.jar
SL_plugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.11.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.11.jar
spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jmx-2.0.8.jar
spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
sunjce_provider.jar
URIUtil-12.3.6.1006.jar
wagon-file-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-2.jar
webreporting-12.3.6.1006.jar
wilog-12.3.6.1006.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

Comment: please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659596/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-web-portlet-context-configurabl) if that would help

Comment: thanks for update vineeth, in applicationcontext.xml i am pointing versionless schema as suggested in that link, so the isue might be other

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: hi jeremie updated stack trace

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223963/confusing-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror) too.

Answer (score 0):

`individualPlanning.jsp` obviously uses the Spring MVC select tag and sets the `disabled` attribute. `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag` in version 4.2.3.RELEASE doesn't have a `setDisabled(String)` method (did it ever?). Instead it's got a `setDisabled(boolean)` inherited from `AbstractHtmlInputElementTag`.

Comment: thanks for the update marcle its weird that they changed argument type to boolean, in our application we are using  spring form: elements selectTag and input for both we are using attributes disabled property which is set by  jstl dynamically as string like <form:selectTag disabled="${disalbed}"/> facing issues lot, the only solution is to change the value from string to boolean or do we have any other solution suggested by spring community

Comment: The value needs to be a boolean. That makes a lot of sense because `disabled` can only ever be true or false. Why would you represent a boolean as a string in the first place.

Comment: current app is in spring 3.2.2.Release we used jstl 1.2 so as per the req disabled will be true or false, we set the value using jstl by checking condition finally we bind the value to spring form:selectTag and inputTag disabled property as sting like "{disabled}", as part of migration we moved to 4.2.3.RELEASE we started facing issues